# Flex : save a resource from url to hard drive?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex

How do I save a resource like "something.rar" from the web, like when it is located on a regular web page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [FileReference.download()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#download%28%29).  There is a complete example shown at the adobe doc page.

Here's the basic idea:

```
var downloadURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.[yourDomain].com/SomeFile.pdf");
var file:FileReference = new FileReference();

// add listeners to `file` to catch errors, handle progress, etc
// (see adobe docs for a complete example of the possible listeners)

file.download(downloadURL, fileName);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the FileReference class. Here's a [tutorial](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/07/28/downloading-files-in-flex-using-the-filereference-class/).